Net booted debian is lagging
I'm testing the debian net-boot capabilities (when a client is loading the whole kernel, file system...etc from a server) and I'm facing some difficulties.
I'm using a supermicro X9 motherboard server as the client (with a new-ish WD red HDD).
It's been a while after I could finally make it work, but now I have another issue: the client can load the kernel (vmlinuz, with an initrd from the syslinux package), load the test filesystem (I made a test filesystem with squashfs-tools on a virtual machine), and it can actually boot. But after that, the computer is just painfully slow and laggy. It's like I tried to use the terminal while it was doing some very CPU-heavy stuff, but actually it's not really using the CPU much. It takes many attempts to even write a command, because half the letters are not caught, it's a struggle.
Is there any way to use "normally" a net booted system like this? Or is this the "normal" performance?

Since you mention squashfs, I assume the entire file system is loaded in RAM, and not a NFS mount? If so performance should be normal.

It didn't look like that was the case, because of the top command I checked, but actually if I set /dev/ram0 as root (in pxelinux.cfg), it works much better.
